# Trim elements from the ends of a list

Tags: code-golf, array

The aim is to trim elements in from the ends of a list, depending on if they are in a second list of "falsey" results.

For example, if the first list is `[-1, 1, 2, 0, -1, 3, -1, 4, -1, -1]` and the second is `[-1]`, then we would remove all leading and trailing `-1`s from the first input, but not any `-1`s in the middle: `[1, 2, 0, -1, 3, -1, 4]`

You may take input in any [allowed method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) and this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122462/discussion-between-makonede-and-nkint) to prevent extended discussion in comments.

Comment: Additionally, I would suggest adding in some more test cases, including ones where the "falsey" list has more than one element

Comment: From being closed, to being reopened, and finally to making it to the HNQ, this post has seen it all...

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <sup><s>37</s></sup> 36 bytes

```hs
f v|g<-reverse.snd.span(`elem`v)=g.g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpBCoAgEAC/socOBSpZHvMlESS0maQiGp76uxnCwDAwl0o3WlvKCfnVC42YMSZkyR8sBeX7HS26PQ9SM12cMl6GaPwDHZywCkL5BivlBCoTgZHAH3OTaKpP@QA)

- -1 byte thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor).

### How?

```hs
f v                     -- define a function f that takes as input a list v of falsey values
  |g<-                  --   inside the definition, define a new function g that...
    reverse             --     reverses...
    .snd                --     the second element of...
    .span               --     a tuple (say (x,y)) where x is the longest prefix of elements that...
      (`elem`v)         --       belong to v...
                        --     and y is the rest of the list
  =g.g                  --   f is defined as the composition g.g (basically apply g twice)
```

Comment: I think you can use `snd.span` for `dropWhile`

Answer (score 6):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
.sF
```

[Try it here!](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=.sF&input=%5B-1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+0%2C+-1%2C+3%2C+-1%2C+4%2C+-1%2C+-1%5D%2C+%5B-1%5D&debug=0)

Comment: I'm not sure how Pyth handles 2 inputs, but is it possible to remove the `F` and take the two inputs separately?

Comment: Pyth takes input from the lines of stdin. Unfortunately, only the first input (i.e. the first line) can be implicit. You could take the inputs separately, but it wouldn't save any bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## Java, 89 bytes

```java
a->b->a.dropWhile(b::contains).sorted((c,d)->-1).dropWhile(b::contains).sorted((c,d)->-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDBSsQwEL33K3JMpA2uetpdAyIIgp568CAe0jStqWkSkulCkf32mjZlF3QPDoHHzHsz8yYdP/Ciq78m1TvrAXUxpwMoTV9UgF32p9wMRoCyhl5dIAN4yfuZckOllUBC8xDQK1cGfWcoxloPwCHCwaoa9ZHFJXhl2vcPxH0bSNLO8bSu25fL6P2zAdlKz/ITMfs8l3/JGGvuJ16wqmCc1t66t0@lJa62W2ENxMWB0BBvkDXGIq9JwYoN@bdw2p18lmMA2VM7AHXxEtAGN5Q7p0ecLFHb4GKTo/hucnSdozm5TXCXIE4ka8/5Sx@852OgPMx34kUirNZSAH5MaH2gYBeaEJIsHbPj9AM)

## Java, 125 bytes

```java
a->b->{int i=-1,j=a.length;for(;b.contains(a[++i]););for(;b.contains(a[--j]););return java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(a,i,j+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBBasMwELz7FTpKjSTqtjclhl4KhZZCcww5rB3ZletIRlqnmOC3u3IcQsFdBMPOrFYzquEEoj58j@bYOo@kjr3s0DTyzQRUyYIuO1ugcVbeqaTt8sYUpGggBPIOxpJzQmJd@YCAEU7OHMgxqnSL3thqtyfgq8Dm2alerjvXxuJuz2/tZGH9alFX2mf8ImZZuRlBZLnIzpEgZiNSXm9ANtpW@KVK56nKZeEsxhcDhd1qZfZMsX8UIeqL4jV23v7J@Ow99CGOtv1H@Qm20hS44fUqZWoY1c33tg@oj9J1KNuYDBtLF0vQzalpKaFtm55a/UMuUc7ROYnngZN7TqbmcYanGUQ6sOudxVYI099QkbJYs6EhGcZf)

Comment: [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVBNa8MwDL3nV@hoj8Ss225JA2MwGHSnHscOTupkThzb2EpLKfntmb1k7FMY5Kf39CTU8SPPukM/y8Eah9AFzEaUil3lyZ9aM@oapdGRtGOlZA214t7DM5caLgmEWOseOYZ0NPIAQ2DJHp3U7csrcNd6umhjPK6exU7qXhx20mPxpFG0wpXpg9F@HIQrfpTLEprtrLKyysrL6U0qQSpWG41hjieKWSF6QikNP2MJzf@RtAJ33OOnSqkF5dOcf2x25A5UmAlb0OIE33Yryb1z/OwZ9xGTbJNCeDcpXKcQwe2S7paUbSj9sgw3GILlb4dV0TBurTqTOJgyXtfCIoktK78/exQDMyMyG46JSi/SyE7JNL8D), using `LinkedList`

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Nice idea. You could post that as another answer.

Comment: Okay, [I've done it](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/222746/16236).

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 19 bytes

```
[ '[ _ ∈ ] trim ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQWFycn1yskFZUqZCbWJKhV5qXmZyfkqpQUJRaUlJZUJSZV6JQnFpYmpqXnFqsYM1VrQCCuoYKhgpGCsYgBhDVQoRqwQxcssZg@dr/0Qrq0QrxCo86OhRiFUqKMnMVYv9XA2XALrHLTSxQ0PsPAA)

### Explanation:

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes two sequences as input and returns one sequence as output.

- `'[ _ ∈ ]` Push a fried quotation to the data stack to be used later by `trim`. Whatever is on top of the data stack gets slotted into the quotation at the `_`. This will be the list of elements to trim.
- `trim` Take a sequence and a quotation and apply the quotation to elements on both ends of the sequence, removing elements for which the quotation returns `t`. Stop when `f` is encountered.
- `∈` Take an object and a sequence and return `t` if the object is in the sequence. Shorthand for `member?`.

Comment: Nice, exactly what I thought of when I saw the challenge.

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 4 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous infix function.

```apl
⌂deb
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1FPU0pq0v@0R20THvX2PepqftS75lHvlkPrjR@1TXzUNzU4yBlIhnh4Bv8/tN5QIU0BRBoqGCkYgFnGYNIETAIxF0TWBK7OELs6AA)

A library function: delete ending blanks using the left argument as a list of what is considered "blanks".

[Notes, comments, and APL implementation.](https://dfns.dyalog.com/n_deb.htm)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 1 byte

```
Ú
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Kz//6N1DXUUDGO5ILSOgpGOgoGOAohjDKFMIJSuYSwA)

A builtin which trims.

Comment: Hey, I was about to post this… >:(

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 46 bytes

```scala
s=>1.to(2)./:(_)((a,_)=>a.reverse dropWhile s)
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tM242wDJR5GxvkwdZVjc2Q)

```
s =>                            //The Set of falsy items
  1.to(2)                       //Make a range [1, 2] to trim twice
    ./:                         //Fold over it,
    (_)                         //starting with the list to trim
    ((a, _) =>                  //The list a and the number, which is ignored
     a.reverse                  //Reverse the list
      dropWhile                 //And drop while
      s)                        //Each item is present in s
```

### Same length, but more boring

```scala
s=>_.dropWhile(s).reverse.dropWhile(s).reverse
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/SumoSpnoTTOqsNWGB4MVGw)

Boring.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (V8), <s>78</s> 62 bytes

*-16 bytes thanks to @Original Original Original VI*

```js
(a,s,g=x=>s.includes(x[0])?g(x.slice(1)):x.reverse())=>g(g(a))
```

**Old:**

```js
a=>n=>(t=z=>z.findIndex(d=>!n.includes(d)),a.slice(t(a),-t([...a].reverse())))
```

Can probably be shortened by a ton

Comment: `f([-1, 1, 2, 0, -1, 3, -1, 4, -1, -1])([2, -1, 1])` seems to give an empty array, am I doing something wrong or is there a bug in the code?

Comment: @CommandMaster Not sure, I just golfed it and that seemed to fix it

Comment: You can get to [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##jYzBCoMwEETv/YocdyEJansqxH6I5BDiGlKCKa6V/H2qeCsUCgPDMPPm6TbHfomvVc15pDqZCk6yDKaYnnWcfXqPxFCGxuIjQNGcoidoEe9FL7TRwgSIpg8QwCFWn2fOiXTKASYYVCvFrk6KRoojXE@7naZaK8U@soiXL/Jn8ddld4aDrx8) by shifting stuff around a bit and not using `findIndex`.

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
[#~1-(*/\.>.*/\)@e.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o5XrDHU1tPRj9Oz0gKSmQ6ref02u1OSMfAWNeEMdBSAyAurRUQBxjCGUCYSKN9RUSAOS/wE)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 68 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b:a[-1]in b and f(a[:-1],b)or a[0]in b and f(a[1:],b)or a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYtLCoAwEEOvkmULI/jpquBJShdTpFjQKuLG04/FDyIEQl6S9djHJXcisZ94DgODKVh2VeNTRgDnAVGxswVQ0MsGdvW/auzbyLqlvKuoyp1Q1BJqwhMMobuDue3inuC@Qeu1FjkB)

Comment: You can save **3 bytes** by using python 2: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpBCsIwEEX3OcXfpYVRTHFV6ElKFgMaOyCTIaSIp49pwcWH93jfvnXLOrXGlBZR2@swupQLBKK4BLrNDp9N3k8wWB/gVWIvaearZRtkdFZEK7i1NZAvniZCINzJv/zp/4VI6BccjB7jDw "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: @qwatry That's a significantly different answer; you should post it as your own.

Comment: Ok. Yeah, I was wondering if I should.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>57</s> 55 bytes

```r
function(x,y,`+`=cumprod)x[!+x%in%y&!rev(+rev(x)%in%y)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/LCsIwEEX3/YoUaU1oFlZQMNAvEaGPxDZiJ5Kkkn59TCqKXbiZxZ055zLaWy1HAdxU/jpBZ6UC7OhM66Kuuml8aMWJO6eFyyRkc55q8cRFHI4sCbl4V5Ws3CXJBt0mY5EdBBol53eBMFewDUmoQA3MdpDQE5Z8KkPRgR1JJFvRS4CwRvkXftsiG5XGNtqu4Q6XbL8o1g6KwsGPaHG0yg4xN38c9BSeIMS/AA)

Finds matching elements (`x %in% y`) as vector of `TRUE/FALSE` values, and calculates the cumulative product (`cumprod`, re-assigned to `+` here to save bytes) to convert everything after the first `FALSE` to zero.  Then does the same from the other end (by `rev`ersing `x` and the `cumprod`).  Finally, negates (`!`) to select only the non-terminal-matching elements of `x`.

Comment: I had some hopelessly complicated scheme with `outer(x,y,'==')`, didn't even think about `%in%`!

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to Leo*

```
‼(↔↓€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDHo1HbVMetU1@1LTm////0YY6pjpmOpY6hgaxII6RjrGOCVjIXMcCIgwA)

**How?**

`↔↓€` removes the falsy elements from one end of the list, and then flips it:

```
 ↓    # drop the longest prefix of arg2 with elements that satisfy:
  €   # are present in arg1
↔     # then reverse the result
```

So we just need to do this twice (to remove from both ends of the list, and to restore the list to its original orientation):
`(` groups `↔↓€` together (the parentheses are automatically closed at the end of the program), and the higher-order function `‼` runs a function provided as an argument twice.

Comment: Wanna do something twice? There's a builtin for that‼ [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//1HDHo1HbVMetU1@1LTm////0YY6pjpmOpY6hgaxII6RjrGOCVjIXMcCIgwA "Husk – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 64 bytes

```python
a,f=input()
for i in-1,0:
 while a and a[i]in f:a.pop(i)
print a
```

The `a and` is necessary if the falsey list, `f`, contains all the elements of `a` and the completely stripped list will be empty. Without it, the program errors with `IndexError: list index out of range`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYpBCoMwEEX3OcXfRWEqjXQl9CSSxYCmDpTJECKlp0@t4OLDe7xv37plHVtjSk9R22vXu5QLBKK3QPfJ4bPJewWDdQHPEkWRJh4sWye9syJawa3NgXzxNBIC4UH@5U@/FiLhuODPOGL8AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/k////0bqGOgpAZKSjYKCjAOIYQygTCKVrGAtREwsA)

A builtin that does exactly this. Works with multiple "falsey" values as well: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/k////0bpGOgq6hjoKQARkGUA4xhDKBEiBpWOB6gxBnFgA)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 56 bytes

Expects `(a)(b)`, where **a** is the array to trim, using the values in the set **b**.

```javascript
a=>b=>(g=a=>a.reverse().filter(i=c=>i|=!b.has(c)))(g(a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBCsMgEER/xd52QaVpe938RI8lB2NXaxEtKuml/24NgYE3D4Z5m81UW8KnqZSf3B11Q/NKM3gaxejCG5fKgNqF2LhAIEtz@NFp1S9TwSIieDCI3eZUc2QdswcHDzVJMXKR4izFLtcDtwNqWhASf8Wd2z5exlH/Aw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 33 bytes

```
#//.{e=#|##&@@#2,a___,e...}:>{a}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1lfX6861Va5RllZzcFB2UgnMT4@XidVT0@v1squOrFW7X9AUWZeiYJDenS1rqGOoY6RjoEOkGEMIkxABEi0VgcsWRv7/z8A)

-6 bytes and correction from @att

Comment: How do you take a list to trim on? It seems like it can only take a single falsey value, though maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @CommandMaster fixed..

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1lfX6861Va5RllZzcFB2UgnMT4@XidVT0@v1squOrFW7X9AUWZeiYJDenS1rqGOoY6RjoEOkGEMIkxABEi0VgcsWRv7/z8A) (`Fold` is also insufficient if the ends of the list aren't ordered the same way as in the falsy list)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 70 bytes

```
func[b t][while[find t b/1][take b]while[find t last b][take/last b]b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1BDsIgEEX3nOKn@6ZimxhdeAi3k1lAgbSxUoMYj4@D7UYWP2/yXkLyrty8I1bhUsI7jmSRmT7TvHgKc3TIsJ1myubuYflPLOYldnPdflguYU3ejBPIVKkgj1oNjSMOEOjrDHVazbvlLeulGaSqvtJJYo2zcM8gWQysmJ5pjhn0WBcHg6a9NvhxQP2Syxc)

## Using `parse`, 123 bytes

```
func[b t][r: copy[]foreach n t[append r reduce['quote n '|]]take/last r
parse b[remove some r to[any r end]remove some r]b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1BbsJADEX3OcUXG1YRhERCsOAQ3VpeTDKOiiAzgzOphMTdU09bFvXi60nv21bx64d44mo8r@MSBuqRmfSMIaYn8RhV3PCJgEwuJQkeChW/DELbxxKzmNq@mLO7ye7u5gytktNZ0JPKFL8Ec5zEtnIkF54GdoT/Ke55fT8ih56pgg3VDRocsIdBW6IrUTf8Z/m31lqns1bxhY5WbnAybhlkiY4rpqTXkEFTvHs4bOrLBj88orzk9Rs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 52 bytes

```
m`^|$
,
(^)?,(([^,]+,)(?=.*¶.*,\3))*(¶.*)?(?(1)|$)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/NyGuRoVLh0sjTtNeR0MjOk4nVltHU8PeVk/r0DY9LZ0YY01NLQ0QU9New17DULNGRZPr/39dQx1DHSMdAx0gwxhEmIAIXUMuXUMA) Explanation:

```
m`^|$
,
```

Wrap both lists in additional commas.

```
(^)?,
```

Record whether this match is at the very start, but at the very least start at a comma.

```
(([^,]+,)(?=.*¶.*,\3))*
```

Match any number of terms which exist in the second array.

```
(¶.*)?
```

Optionally match the second array.

```
(?(1)|$)
```

If the match did not begin at the start, then it must end at the end.

Delete the matching values.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 86 bytes

```java
l->b->{while(b.contains(l.peek()))l.pop();while(b.contains(l.getLast()))l.pollLast();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBNa8MwDL3nV@hoj8Ss225JA2MwGHSnHscOTupkThzb2EpLKfntmb1k7FMY5Kf39CTU8SPPukM/y8Eah9AFzEaUil3lyZ9aM@oapdGRtGOlZA214t7DM5caLgmEWOseOYZ0NPIAQ2DJHp3U7csrcNd6umhjPK6exU7qXhx20mPxpFG0wpXpg9F@HIQrfpTLEprtrLKyysrL6U0qQSpWG41hjieKWSF6QikNP2MJzf@RtAJ33OOnSqkF5dOcf2x25A5UmAlb0OIE33Yryb1z/OwZ9xGTbJNCeDcpXKcQwe2S7paUbSj9sgw3GILlb4dV0TBurTqTOJgyXtfCIoktK78/exQDMyMyG46JSi/SyE7JNL8D)

Uses a `LinkedList` as input/output.

Comment: You could also make it accept the more general `Deque` interface.

Comment: @iota Yes that was my first idea, but since the challenge speaks of list, I tried to stay in the spirit of it.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 70 bytes

```
=LET(x,A1#,r,ROW(x),y,IF(x>-1,r,""),FILTER(x,(r>=MIN(y))*(r<=MAX(y))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), <s>227</s> 215 bytes

```
z(A)=length(A)
h(l,a,k)=\left\{l[a]=k:0,1\right\}
f(a,b)=\sum_{n=1}^{z(b)}(1-h(b,n,a))
s=f(A,B)
j(A,B)=A[\sum_{N=1}^{z(s)}N(1-h(s,N,0))\prod_{a=1}^{N-1}h(s,a,0)...z(A)]
p=j(A,B)
q=j(p[z(p)...1],B)
m(A,B)=q[z(q)...1]
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gslxnrvixl)

[Try It On Desmos!(Prettified Version)](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dpmeu1owbc)

Final function is \$m(a,b)\$, where \$a\$ is the list that is being trimmed, and \$b\$ is the list of "falsey" values that are trimmed from \$a\$.

Much harder than I initially anticipated because Desmos has limited list functionality. Hopefully it's fine if I output an one-element list with the one element being `undefined`(`[undefined]`) when the output is supposed to be an empty list(`[]`). If it isn't fine then tell me and I can fix(but it would cost more bytes ☹️)

Note: Not too sure why, but you can't directly paste the code into Desmos for some reason. You have to paste each expression one at a time in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/WheatWizard/haskell-golfing-library), 14 bytes

```
jn m<rv.^dW<fe
```

[Try it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNxczcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRMDS0pI0XYsNabZZeQq5NkVlNjYp4TZpqRDhm765iZl5CrYKKflcCgoFRQoqCmkK0QaxQKxjoGMEhCDSIBZJ0lDHKBZM6hhDsZGOIRgbxkIMXbAAQgMA)

(`.^` has been renamed to `<<` since this was posted)

## Explanation

To start we want to do the much simpler:

```
f x y=rv$dW(fe x)$rv$dw(fe x)y
```

This drops all things in `x` off the front, reverses it, then drops all things in `x` off the new front and reverses it back.

From here we can start by removing the `y`.

```
f x=rv<dW(fe x)<rv<dw(fe x)
```

Now we have the expression `rv<dW(fe x)` twice so let's fix that. `jn` will take a function on two arguments and pass the same value as both of its arguments.

```
f x=(rv<dW(fe x))<(rv<dW(fe x))
f x=jn m(rv<dW(fe x))
```

Now `x` is at the end so we can eta-reduce it away as well:

```
f x=jn m<rv.^dW<fe
```

### Reflection

Usually I would use `Rv` to reverse a list however `.^` next to `Rv` breaks the Haskell parser, so I had to use `rv` instead.  I've been aware of this danger for a while now and this was a pretty close call. I will probably rename `.^` to `<<`.

"Compose a function with itself" achieved here with `jn m` is something that should probably have it's own name. It would have saved a byte here at least.

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](http://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Feb-17)</sup>, 11 bytes

```
▽¬↥⇌∩\×⇌.∊,
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_9_0__ZiDihpAg4pa9wqzihqXih4ziiKlcw5fih4wu4oiKLAoKZiBbMyA3XSBbMyAzIDcgNCA3IDEgMyA1IDMgNyA3XQpmIFsxXSBbMSAxIDEgMV0KZiBbNSAyXSBbNSA1IDIgMyA0XQo=)

Answer (score 0):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 16 bytes

```
(⌽(∨`·∧˝≠⌜)/⊢)⍟2
```

Takes the list as its right argument and the elements to trim as its left argument. [Try it at BQN online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgKOKMvSjiiKhgwrfiiKfLneKJoOKMnCkv4oqiKeKNnzIKCjPigL814oC/OSBGIDPigL8x4oC/NOKAvzHigL814oC/OeKAvzLigL824oC/NeKAvzPigL81)

#### Explanation

```
(⌽(∨`·∧˝≠⌜)/⊢)⍟2
         ≠⌜         Make an inequality table of the two lists: 0 when elements are
                    equal, 1 when they aren't
       ∧˝           Fold each column on logical AND: 1 for elements in the list
                    that aren't one of the elements to trim, 0 for those that are
    ∨`·             Scan with logical OR: keep leading run of 0s but turn everything
                    after the first 1 into 1s
   (       )/⊢      Remove elements of the original list that correspond to 0s in
                    that list; keep elements that correspond to 1s
 ⌽                  Reverse
(              )⍟2  Do that twice
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 59 bytes

```perl
$_=<>;for$i(0,-1){splice@F,$i,1while/(^| )$F[$i]\b/}say"@F"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tbGzjotv0glU8NAR9dQs7q4ICczOdXBTUclU8ewPCMzJ1VfI65GQVPFLVolMzYmSb@2OLFSycFN6f9/XUMFQwUjBQMFIMMYRJiACF1DLl3Df/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7rJuYAAA)